# PHP cannot extract array values by index

Tags: php, arrays

Ok So I'm making a shop at the moment, to store the shopping cart I'm using arrays of $basketItems, $basketWeights and $basketQuantities. Each index will relate to an item in the basket.

My code works by looping round each of the items in the basket (according to the arrays I have) then pulling the relevant information from the database.

The code works great for the first row it pulls from the database however this fails as soon as it reaches the second item, yet I have no idea why.

The problem seems to occur with not being able to get the required value at correct index from the $weights or $prices arrays. You'll notice in the code, to check whether or not the array $weights is forming correctly I have echo'd it, also echo'd the index I want to retrieve, which looks ok, the only problem is that it doesn't echo anything (as far as I can tell!)

The code is as follows

```
    <?
/*
$basketItems
$basketWeights
$basketProducts

are arrays, each value stores the index of the item relating to the product in the database */

//show basket, go through all the basket items, the retrieves relevant information from the database
for($index = 0; $index < sizeof($basketItems); $index++)
{
    //get product at this index
    $getProduct = mysql_query("SELECT * from shop_products where prid='".$basketItems[$index]."' limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
    $product = mysql_fetch_array($getProduct);
    //weights is an array for each product ie 100, 200, 500
    $weights = explode(",", $product['prweights']);
    $weightIndex = $basketWeights[$index];
    $prices = explode(",", $product['prprices']);
?> <tr>
<td><b><? print_r(array_values($weights)); ?></b></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><? echo($product['prtitle']); ?></td>
    <td><? echo ("$weightIndex/$weights[$weightIndex]"); ?>g</td>
    <td><? echo($basketQuantities[$index]); ?></td>
    <td><? echo $prices[$weightIndex]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo ($prices[$weightIndex] * $basketQuantities[$index]); ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <?

  }
?>
```

And the result can be seen here:
http://www.jamesmoorhouse.co.uk/images/shop.png

As you can see from the screenshot, it just doesn't echo anything where it should echo the result from the array seen above each product.

The format of testing for the 2nd column is arrayIndex/arrayValueAtIndex g

Comment: you are printing `array_values($weights)` , but what returns `<? print_r($weights); ?>` (note that array_values may assign new indexes)

Comment: This still returns the same
Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 250 [2] => 500 )
Planters Breakfast  0/100g  3  2.00  6   
Array ( [0] => 100 )
Planters' Afternoon  0/g  3   0

I thought that might have been happening at first, so  I tried to empty the array every time it looped the for statement, but that didn't work

Comment: Strange, what returns mysql_num_rows() after the 1st entry?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of notes:

- please move sizeof() out of for-loop. do the sizeof() calc before.
- please remove () from echo. not needed.
- you might do calculations before outputting
- you might use unset() at the end of the for loop, on vars newly created inside the for-loop. that would prevent overwriting stuff or reusing data from iteration before.
- i would remove the needs to use explode() when fetching them and implode() when updating/storing them. just store/fetch the data directly in the database.
- you know all basketItem product ids (prids), just ask the database for the whole array  of basketitems (prids=1,2,3,4,123) at once. mysql syntax: `WHERE prids IN('1','2','3')";` call the whole result set via `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. then foreach() the array. this reduces calls to the db.
- to answer the question: i hope i'm not totally off track, but i would say that the error is `$weightIndex = $basketWeights[$index];` could you please provide the $basketWeights array data. the relationship does not fit: basketWeights must be assoc, i guess, like basketWeights[prdid][weights_index].